Non-Hermitian Models from PythTB Library
I tried to make a non-hermitian model of a simple square lattice using the PythTb library but I got to know from a video that they don't allow non-hermitian models. But on the website the set_hop paramter had a argument of 'allow_conjugate_pair=False' the description of the argument

allow_conjugate_pair – Default value is False. If set to True code will allow user to specify hopping i $\rightarrow$ j+R even if conjugate-pair hopping j $\rightarrow$ i-R has been specified. If both terms are specified, code will still count each term two times.

I'm not sure I get entirely what this means but would this be useful for defining non-hermiticity?
source: https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/pythtb/usage.html

Given the statement that "If both terms are specified, code will still count each term two times." I would assume that this is not useful for defining non-Hermitian models. Indeed, it is also written that

Hopping in the opposite direction is automatically included by the code since
$$H_{ji}(-\mathbf{R}) = \left[ H_{ij}(\mathbf{R})\right]^\star$$

The source code also contains a number of checks to verify that the matrices are Hermitian, and uses numpy.linalg.eigvalsh and numpy.linalg.eigh to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Both these methods are for complex Hermitian or real symmetric matrices. In general, dealing with left and right eigenvectors of non-Hermitian matrices and especially the sometimes very numerically ill-conditioned behavior at exceptional points can be challenging, so I'm not sure if general use packages have been made available.
